# Group by, filter top rows while customise aggregating columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of national sales and I'd like to

1. group by `state`, `Store` and `YearMonth`, and
2. filter the top 10 stores(not shown in the expected output due to small sample data table) by total `Sales` in each state (should this be done in a separate step?) while
3. aggregating other columns in different ways: 'Sales':'sum', 'Qty':'sum', 'Item': join the unique values, I'm thinking about using custom aggregation like `df1= df.astype(str).groupby(['State','Store', 'YearMonth']).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))` but can I do this together with other aggregations at the same time?

df:

```
    YearMonth   State   Store   Qty  Sales          Item
0   2020-06     AA      JW442   1.0  100            SP006
1   2020-06     AA      JW442   1.0  1200           SP007
2   2019-09     CC      JW600   4.0  700            SP020
3   2019-05     AA      JW100   5.0  30             SP00
4   2019-05     AA      JW100   4.0  8500           SP5
                                ...
```

Expected output:

```
    State    Store  YearMonth  Qty   Sales          Item
0   AA       JW100  2019-05    9.0   85300          SP00, SP5
             JW442  2020-06    2.0   1300           SP006,SP007
             ...
             
2   CC       JW600  2019-09    4.0   700            SP020

                               ...
```

Question:

What's the best way to do this? For filtering top 10 stores by `Sales` should I do it in a separate step? I learnt about `nlargest`, is it appropriate to use it here?

---

Reproducible example:

```
pd.DataFrame({'YearMonth': {0: Period('2020-07', 'M'),
  1: Period('2020-06', 'M'),
  2: Period('2019-09', 'M'),
  3: Period('2019-03', 'M'),
  4: Period('2019-05', 'M'),
  5: Period('2019-01', 'M'),
  6: Period('2019-03', 'M'),
  7: Period('2019-05', 'M'),
  8: Period('2019-05', 'M'),
  9: Period('2019-05', 'M')},
 'State': {0: 'QLD',
  1: 'AA',
  2: 'AA',
  3: 'CC',
  4: 'AA',
  5: 'SA',
  6: 'AA',
  7: 'CC',
  8: 'AA',
  9: 'CC'},
 'Store': {0: 'HJR411-140',
  1: 'JW442',
  2: 'JW442',
  3: 'JW600',
  4: 'JW600',
  5: 'JW442',
  6: 'JW600',
  7: 'JW100',
  8: 'JW100',
  9: 'JW100'},
 'Qty': {0: 1.0,
  1: 1.0,
  2: 4.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 4.0,
  5: 1.0,
  6: 1.0,
  7: 22.0,
  8: 1.0,
  9: 1.0},
 'Sales': {0: 118.17000000000002,
  1: 49.1075,
  2: 725.4,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 785.85,
  5: 457.145,
  6: 619.814,
  7: 1542.97,
  8: 266.5,
  9: 159.95200000000003},
 'Item': {0: 'SP006',
  1: 'SP007',
  2: 'SP007',
  3: 'SP020',
  4: 'SP020',
  5: 'SP5',
  6: 'SP5',
  7: 'SP007',
  8: 'SP00',
  9: 'SP00'}})
```

---

Edit 1:

Tried:

```
# Get The Largest store values by total sales
stores = df.groupby('Store')['Sales'].sum().nlargest(10).index

df = (
    df[df['Store'].isin(stores)]  # Filter to include only largest stores
        .groupby(['Store', 'State', 'YearMonth'])  # Groupby
        .agg({'Qty': 'sum',  # Agg Columns
              'Sales': 'sum',
              'Item': lambda i: ','.join(i.unique())})
).reset_index()
```

and caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-157-6008e53ec50d> in <module>
     22 
     23 df1= (
---> 24     df[df['Store'].isin(stores)]  # Filter to include only largest stores
     25         .groupby(['State', 'Store', 'YearMonth'])  # Groupby
     26         .agg({'Qty': 'sum',  # Agg Columns

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    943             )
    944 
--> 945         result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
    946         if how is None:
    947             return result

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    414 
    415                 try:
--> 416                     result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
    417                 except SpecificationError:
    418 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _agg(arg, func)
    381                 result = {}
    382                 for fname, agg_how in arg.items():
--> 383                     result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
    384                 return result
    385 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _agg_1dim(name, how, subset)
    365                         "nested dictionary is ambiguous in aggregation"
    366                     )
--> 367                 return colg.aggregate(how)
    368 
    369             def _agg_2dim(how):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    253 
    254             if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:
--> 255                 return self._python_agg_general(
    256                     func, *args, engine=engine, engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs, **kwargs
    257                 )

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
   1088 
   1089         if len(output) == 0:
-> 1090             return self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
   1091 
   1092         if self.grouper._filter_empty_groups:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f, data)
    890             data after applying f
    891         """
--> 892         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
    893 
    894         return self._wrap_applied_output(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    211             # group might be modified
    212             group_axes = group.axes
--> 213             res = f(group)
    214             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):
    215                 mutated = True

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in <lambda>(x)
   1056         func = self._is_builtin_func(func)
   1057         if engine != "numba":
-> 1058             f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
   1059 
   1060         # iterate through "columns" ex exclusions to populate output dict

<ipython-input-157-6008e53ec50d> in <lambda>(i)
     26         .agg({'Qty': 'sum',  # Agg Columns
     27               'Sales': 'sum',
---> 28               'Item': lambda i: ','.join(i.unique())})
     29 ).reset_index()
     30 

TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

---

Edit 2:

If I add `.astype(str)` before `groupby` like:

```
# Get The Largest store values by total sales
stores = df.groupby('Store')['Sales'].sum().nlargest(10).index

df = (
    df[df['Store'].isin(stores)]  # Filter to include only largest stores
        .astype(str).groupby(['Store', 'State', 'YearMonth'])  # Groupby
        .agg({'Qty': 'sum',  # Agg Columns
              'Sales': 'sum',
              'Item': lambda i: ','.join(i.unique())})
).reset_index()
```

it will run but the `Qty` and `Sales` would join values as if they are strings, instead of sum.

Comment: top 10 stores by `Sales` is this total sales per store?

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker yes

Comment: @Henry sorry can we do top 10 stores by total Sales per store in each state?

Comment: Can you include a bit of your dataset as a dict? `df.head(10).to_dict()` or similar?

Comment: Do you want the top 10 stores per state? or you want the top 10 stores overall?

Comment: @HenryEcker I want  the top 10 stores per state, sorry about the confusion

Comment: @HenryEcker Please see question edit for the dataset sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created df from the data you created.

**Input df**

```
    YearMonth   State   Store       Qty Sales       Item
0   2020-07     QLD     HJR411-140  1.0 118.1700    SP006
1   2020-06     AA      JW442       1.0 49.1075    SP007
2   2019-09     AA      JW442       4.0 725.4000    SP007
3   2019-03     CC      JW600       0.0 0.0000     SP020
4   2019-05     AA      JW600       4.0 785.8500    SP020
5   2019-01     SA      JW442       1.0 457.1450    SP5
6   2019-03     AA      JW600       1.0 619.8140    SP5
7   2019-05     CC      JW100       22.0    1542.9700   SP007
8   2019-05     AA      JW100       1.0 266.5000    SP00
9   2019-05     CC      JW100       1.0 159.9520    SP00
```

Because of sample data tested `top 2 stores by sales in each state`. You can replace the varible `top_n=10` for top 10 store by sales for each state.

```
top_n = 2
grouped = df.groupby(['State', 'Store', 'YearMonth'])
df = grouped.agg({'Sales':'sum', 'Qty':'sum', 'Item':list})
df = df.groupby(['State','Store'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(top_n,'Sales'))
df
```

**Output**

```
                               Sales        Qty Item
State   Store   YearMonth           
AA     JW100    2019-05        266.5000     1.0 [SP00]
       JW442    2019-09        725.4000     4.0 [SP007]
                2020-06        49.1075      1.0 [SP007]
       JW600    2019-05        785.8500     4.0 [SP020]
                2019-03        619.8140     1.0 [SP5]
CC     JW100    2019-05        1702.9220    23.0    [SP007, SP00]
       JW600    2019-03        0.0000       0.0 [SP020]
QLD    HJR411-140   2020-07    118.1700     1.0 [SP006]
SA     JW442    2019-01        457.1450     1.0 [SP5]
```

Comment: Hi Uts, thank you for the solution. It seems the output returns the top 2 `YearMonth` rather than stores?  Is it possible to return the top store with all `YearMonth` values?